# Notification in loopback

Tags: node.js, sockets, notifications, loopbackjs

I am using a loopback framework for my Backend(API). I have 2 separate loopback applications running in different ports...

Now if there is a change in the model (document is inserted in MongoDb) of APP1, it should give a notification to APP2 that some documents is inserted.

I have gone through the documentation for loopback, but it describes using PUSH notification for IOs and Android. But in this case it is different.

I have gone through "socket.io", what is the best way to implement using socket.io?

Also how can i listen for a document inserted in MongoDB?

Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your model is a `PersistedModel`, you can use the [change-stream](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/PersistedModel+REST+API#PersistedModelRESTAPI-CreateChangeStream).